# CSS: element has 'display: block' and doesn't start a new line

Tags: css, flexbox

Please take a look on the following code:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
}

div {
  border: solid;
}

#first {
  flex: 1
}

#second {
  flex: 1
}

#third {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="third"></div>
</header>
```

This code gives three rectangles that lie one next to the other.
However, if you inspect each rectangle, you'll see in dev-tools

[image]

that these rectangles has `display: block`.

However, I know that when an element has a `display: block` property, it means that the element starts a new line. As you can see, it's not the case. All three rectangles are placed in the same line.

How can you explain this?

Comment: Flex rendering overrides the div behaviour but does not cancel the display:block

Comment: Because parent selector has a `display:flex` property. So it makes items either as a row or as a column. Dev tool showing `display:block;` that is user agent style sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I know that when an element has a display: block property, it means that the element starts a new line.

Your information is wrong because the display property alone never tells us if we will have a new line or not.

Let's take another example without flexbox:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:2px solid;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You can clearly notice that the elements have the computed value of `display` equal to block but they don't start on a new line due to the float property. Same thing happen with flexbox, CSS grid, position:absolute and many others combination of properties.

All this is defined in the specification.

For float elements: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats

> If the current box is left-floating, and there are any left-floating boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document, then for each such earlier box, either the left outer edge of the current box must be to the right of the right outer edge of the earlier box, or its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box. Analogous rules hold for right-floating boxes.

For flexbox: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/

> The display value of a flex item is **blockified**: ...
>
> The flex-direction property specifies how **flex items are placed in the flex container**, by setting the direction of the flex container’s main axis. This determines the direction in which flex items are laid out.

The default direction is `row`

---

You simply need to find the part of the specification dealing with the properties you are using to find how your elements will be placed in the document and you will clearly see that `display` alone isn't enough to define this.

Answer (score 0):

Your container div is set to be displayed as `flex` - so all of its children will inherit the display mode from the parent (and thus, display inline). You can set how they're displayed by specifying the `flex-direction`. Setting it to display as `column` will make all of the child elements display under one another.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  /* Add this */
  flex-direction:column;
}
div {
  border: solid;
}
#first {
  flex:1
  
}
#second {
  flex:1
}
#third {
  flex:1
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="header">
      <div id="first"></div>
      <div id="second"></div>
      <div id="third"></div>
    </header>
  </body>
```

Comment: If the children inherit the display type from their parent, why does dev-tools show that their display is "block" and not "flex"?

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's because your header display flex. If it displays flex, its all children will display in a line. You can change by add flex-direction: column or row (as default)

Answer (score 0):

- **display: flex** is tells your browser, "I wanna use flexbox with this container, please." A div element defaults to display:box.
- An element with this display setting takes up the full width of the
  line it is on. Here is an example of four colored divs in a parent
  div with the default display setting:

[image]